# I want to assign value corresponding to key in dictionary as replacement for column value in pyspark

Tags: dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark, mapping, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write this function in pyspark such that the values stored in mapping_table will get assigned to the values in cat_columns. But, its not working. I have tried many ways. Can you please help me to understand where I am wrong?

def apply_hierarchy_masking(dataframes, mapping, categorical_columns, apply_mask_flag=0): if apply_mask_flag == 1: for i, dataframe in zip(range(len(dataframes)), dataframes): for colmn in cat_cols_list: if colmn in mapping_table: #dataframe = dataframe.withColumn(colmn, mapping[colmn][colmn]) # Create a udf for the mapping function dataframe = dataframe.withColumn(colmn, dataframe[colmn].cast(T.StringType())) mapping_udf = F.udf(lambda x: mapping[colmn].get(x), T.StringType()) # Use the udf to apply the mapping function to the column dataframe = dataframe.withColumn(colmn, mapping_udf(col(colmn))) # # Define a conditional expression that maps values to their masked equivalents # mapping_expr = F.when(dataframe[colmn].isin(list(mapping[colmn])), mapping[colmn][colmn]).otherwise(dataframe[colmn]) # # Apply the conditional expression to the column using withColumn # dataframe = dataframe.withColumn(colmn, mapping_expr) # # Define the mapping function using udf # mapping_udf = F.udf(lambda x: mapping[x][x]) # # Apply the mapping function to the column using withColumn # dataframe = dataframe.withColumn(colmn, mapping_udf(colmn)) else: print(f"Not applying masking for column: {colmn}") # null_count = dataframe.select([col(c).isNull().alias(c) for c in dataframe.columns]).sum().asDict() # print(f"Dataframe {i} null value counts: \n{null_count}") # print(f"Dataframe {i} shape before dropping null values: {dataframe.count()}, {len(dataframe.columns)}") # # Drop the rows with null values # dataframe = dataframe.dropna() # print(f"Dataframe {i} shape after dropping null values: {dataframe.count()}, {len(dataframe.columns)}") # dataframes[i] = dataframe else: print("Not applying hierarchy masking to the given data") return dataframes

I have tried different ways and I have hashed them in this code. But none of them are working. The udf function is not giving error but just returning original values.

Comment: Can you please format your code ?

Comment: I've added an answer let me know if your requirement is different

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need to replace the value of a column (with dictionary value) if the column value is present as a key in the dictionary.

You can create a DF out of that dictionary.

```
dict={"value_1": "value_x", "value_2": "value_y"}
dict_df=spark.createDataFrame([(k,v) for k,v in dict.items()], ["key","value"])
```

and then perform a join like this (to replace value of `column_a`):

```
df.alias("df1")\
.join(F.broadcast(dict_df.alias("df2")), F.col("column_a")==F.col("key"), "left")\
.withColumn("column_a", F.coalesce(F.col("df2.value"), F.col("df1.column_a")))\
.show()
```

Input DF:

[image: Input]

Dict DF:

[image: Dict]

Output (You can drop the intermediate columns, I kept it for understanding):

[image: Output]